# show how many messages application got from topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, micrometer

I have Spring Boot application with producer and several consumers. I need to show kafka metrics.
For this purpose I added micrometer dependency and update my consumer and producers configs with this
producerFactory.addListener(new MicrometerProducerListener<>(meterRegistry))

This option doesn't show how many messages application got from topic xxx. Only show common count messages by consumer. Example
kafka_producer_record_send_total{client_id="producer-1",kafka_version="2.7.1",spring_id="producerFactory.producer-1",} 4.0
How can I expire my configurations for more detail metrics.

Comment: If you are looking at producer metrics only, you'll never see "how many messages were consumed from topic X" ... Have you tried adding metrics listener to a consumer client instead?

Comment: I tried add listener for consumer and producer and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

JMX metrics should already be available natively in Kafka consumer client (not from a ProducerFactory)

> ```
> MBean:
> kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=”{client-id}”,topic=”{topic}”
> ```
>
> `records-consumed-total`

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/monitoring.html#consumer-metrics

Comment: I found this metrics!!Thank you! And what about producer metrics? Are there same metrics for producers?

Comment: Same docs page shows producer metrics as well, yes

Comment: I also found needed metrics. Thank you very much!